# Give and get the I/O of java program from the source

Tags: java

How can I write a program which will run another java program (should invoke that program) give the input to that program from this program and get the output and print the output to a file.

Answer (score 8):

Use [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Example:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
Process p = pb.start();
InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();


// Write to input of the program using outputstream here
...

// Read output of program from input stream here
// ...


FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
BufferedInputStream bIn = new BufferedInputStream(in);

byte buf = new byte[4096];
int count;

while ((count = bIn.read(buf)) != -1) {
    fileOut.write(buf, 0, count);
}

...
fileOut.close();
bIn.close();

// Exception handling is left as an exercise for the reader :-P
```

Comment: I hadn't heard of the ProcessBuilder class before. Thanks for the tip!